# Preserving The Current State Of A Multi Step Angular Form

Tags: angularjs

I want to put together a workflow type form built with Angular. I'm looking to find a common angular pattern in a situation where a multi-state angular form is being processed. I'm going to use a generic example to illustrate the problem.

**USER SCENARIO:**
As A User, I want to register to a newsletter.

**Story Decomposition** Scenario: An Incomplete Registration

- I navigate to the website: http://www.yomomma.org/register
- An Angular Form Is Presented With Username, Password, Email, Phone #, etc.,
- I Enter the information in for the form and select the next button.
- Now, on the second state, ie http://www.yomomma.org/newsletter-preferences, it is asking me my newsletter preferences like how frequent I'd like to fill my inbox, what type of newsletter package I'm interested in, blah blah.
- I realize that I need to goto http://www.yodaddy.org/merica because father's day is coming and I want to buy him a gun.
- Now, I go back to the http://www.yomomma.org/register state

**How can I automagically make my angular app know I was on the second page of this workflow?**

Thank you peeps.